# How to set a range of tolerence in Pandas merge_asof?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dask, timedelta

I'm trying to merge two time-series data using pandas merge_asof and tolerance level.

[Pandas document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) gives me a nice demonstration of how to use tolerance, but I was wondering if I can use a range of tolerance.

```
>>> quotes
                     time ticker     bid     ask
0 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   GOOG  720.50  720.93
1 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT   51.95   51.96
2 2016-05-25 13:30:00.030   MSFT   51.97   51.98
3 2016-05-25 13:30:00.041   MSFT   51.99   52.00
4 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.50  720.93
5 2016-05-25 13:30:00.049   AAPL   97.99   98.01
6 2016-05-25 13:30:00.072   GOOG  720.50  720.88
7 2016-05-25 13:30:00.075   MSFT   52.01   52.03

>>> trades
                     time ticker   price  quantity
0 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT   51.95        75
1 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT   51.95       155
2 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.77       100
3 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.92       100
4 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL   98.00       100


>>> pd.merge_asof(trades, quotes,
...                       on='time',
...                       by='ticker',
...                       tolerance=pd.Timedelta('10ms'),
...                       allow_exact_matches=False)
                     time ticker   price  quantity     bid     ask
0 2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   MSFT   51.95        75     NaN     NaN
1 2016-05-25 13:30:00.038   MSFT   51.95       155   51.97   51.98
2 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.77       100     NaN     NaN
3 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   GOOG  720.92       100     NaN     NaN
4 2016-05-25 13:30:00.048   AAPL   98.00       100     NaN     NaN
```

Above example merges only when the time gap is strictly less than '10ms', with `direction='backward'`.

I'm wondering if I can use a range like between 10minutes and 20minutes with `direction='forward'` such that it merges the closest one that happened more than 10 minutes later, but less than 20 minutes?

edit: I've added the sample data to the post (from Pandas doc). With above example, say I want to merge with Timedelta level between '5ms' and '10ms' or so.

Comment: I've added the sample data.